# Do humans have the hyaloid canal, after all?

Tags: human-biology, human-eye

Most Google Images results for "eye anatomy" are pictures of eyes that don't have the hyaloid canal while some do ([proof](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=949&q=eye+anatomy&oq=eye+anatomy&gs_l=img.3..0l10.22.1421.0.2147.11.7.0.4.4.0.304.574.5j3-1.6.0....0...1ac.1.54.img..1.10.590.SB42fKc_bxg)). Do humans have it, after all, or not? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, humans do have the hyaloid canal.

[image]

Schematic diagram of the human eye ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyaloid_canal))

For function and other information, please refer to [this journal article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1465472/).

Comment: What, in your opinion, justifies that it is missing in the vast majority of eye anatomy images? I don't even remember seeing it in my high school biology textbook.

Comment: @user132181 Can you send me links to a few such images?

Comment: Look at [the mentioned Google Images search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=949&q=eye+anatomy&oq=eye+anatomy&gs_l=img.3..0l10.22.1421.0.2147.11.7.0.4.4.0.304.574.5j3-1.6.0....0...1ac.1.54.img..1.10.590.SB42fKc_bxg).

Comment: @user132181 I would have to say that most of them are showing you the full eye while you get to see the Hyaloid canal if you go for a cross-section view. In full eye images, the hyaloid canal would not be marked.